# rg.apache.spark.SparkException: Invalid master URL: spark://tasks.501393358-spark-master:7077

Tags: apache-spark, docker

I have 2 spark clusters - global spark master, 100-spark-master.
I created 2 spark workers one for global spark master and one for 100-spark-master. All are created in single node.

global spark worker is up and attached to global spark master.
But 100-spark-worker is not up and i get the following exception.

How to resolve this?

Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Invalid master URL: spark://tasks.100-spark-master:7077
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.extractHostPortFromSparkUrl(Utils.scala:2330)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcAddress$.fromSparkURL(RpcAddress.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker$$anonfun$13.apply(Worker.scala:714)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker$$anonfun$13.apply(Worker.scala:714)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)

The way i create these services are

## Global Network:

docker service create --name global-spark-master --limit-cpu 8 --limit-memory 24GB --reserve-cpu 4 --reserve-memory 12GB --network global --network xyzservice  --with-registry-auth pricecluster1:5000/nimbus/xinnici_spark:2.0.2 sh -c  '/opt/spark/bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master -i tasks.global-spark-master'

docker service create --name global-spark-worker --limit-cpu 8 --limit-memory 24GB --reserve-cpu 4 --reserve-memory 12GB --network global --network xyzservice  --with-registry-auth pricecluster1:5000/nimbus/xinnici_spark:2.0.2 sh -c  '/opt/spark/bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker spark://tasks.global-spark-master:7077'

## Specific network:

docker service create --name 100-spark-master --limit-cpu 2 --limit-memory 12GB --reserve-cpu 2 --reserve-memory 6GB --network 100 --network xyzservice  --with-registry-auth pricecluster1:5000/nimbus/xinnici_spark:2.0.2 sh -c  '/opt/spark/bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master -i tasks.100-spark-master'

docker service create --name 100-spark-worker --limit-cpu 2 --limit-memory 12GB --reserve-cpu 1 --reserve-memory 6GB --network 100 --network xyzservice  --with-registry-auth pricecluster1:5000/nimbus/xinnici_spark:2.0.2 sh -c  '/opt/spark/bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker spark://tasks.100-spark-master:7077'